# CPU frequencies wrong

Tags: cpu, frequency

So after I installed Ubuntu to my laptop, I was amazed at how quiet the laptop became. Previously on Windows the fans constantly ran at full speed. However, when I started gaming on it, framerates became a huge problem. They're nothing like the framerates achieved on Windows. Same with High Performance mode, quiet fans, crappy framerates. So I ran lscpu, and it returned with this:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          12
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-11
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              6
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           166
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10710U CPU @ 1.10GHz
Stepping:                        0
CPU MHz:                         1097.644
CPU max MHz:                     1100.0000
CPU min MHz:                     400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        3199.92
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       192 KiB
L1i cache:                       192 KiB
L2 cache:                        1.5 MiB
L3 cache:                        12 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-11
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RS
                                 B filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rd
                                 tscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts 
                                 rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperf
                                 mperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx e
                                 st tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_
                                 1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer
                                  aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowpre
                                 fetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs 
                                 ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpr
                                 iority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1
                                  avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx sma
                                 p clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 x
                                 saves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hw
                                 p_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_ca
                                 pabilities
```

1100 MHz max frequency? 400 MHz minimum frequency? For reference 1100MHz should be minimum frequency and maximum frequency should be 4.7 GHz. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Probably a newer kernel version is needed for such new CPU.

Comment: kernel is already at 5.11.0-22-generic though

Comment: Looks to me as though turbo is disabled. If you are using the default intel_pstate CPU frequency driver then do `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` where "0" indicated enabled and "1" indicates disabled. And no, 1.1GHz is not the min frequency, it is the base frequency or max if turbo is disabled.

Comment: ok it's been a long time, i forgot about this, but yea Doug's method worked